# When talking with a client, what should I do with my hands?

Tags: professionalism, clients, behavior

When talking with a client, what should I do with my hands?

Should I put them in my back pockets? Let them hang? Put them over my pockets?

This may sound stupid, but it is an important component to keep a professional look. Also, I don't want to look silly or weird or uninterested to the clients.

I have no training whatsoever on how to behave with a client, and I never will. I learn a lot from here and by try-error-hear an angry boss.

There's no HR, I can't ask my boss, Google doesn't have a satisfying answer and this is literally driving me insane!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23740/discussion-on-question-by-ismael-miguel-when-talking-with-a-client-what-should). Keep in mind comments are for clarification/questions of the asker, not extended discussion - use the chat room for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Short answer: **carry a notebook and pen** - it'll give your hands something to do. You can switch both items to a single hand for handshaking purposes. You can also use them to make notes, so you'll seem (and possibly *be*) well-organised.

Long answer:

- Don't worry about it. Kind clients will be understanding, average clients won't care, egotistical clients will be flattered that you're nervous of them. If you just chill out and stop thinking about it then it'll stop mattering.
- Read (but don't take too seriously, there's a lot of pseudoscience in this field) some articles about body language, e.g.

  - https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/spycatcher/201001/body-language-the-hands
  - http://www.huffingtonpost.com/vanessa-van-edwards/how-introverts-can-use-bo_b_4578260.html
  - http://www.forbes.com/sites/carolkinseygoman/2013/08/21/12-body-language-tips-for-career-success/
  - http://jamesclear.com/body-language-how-to-be-confident
- Find something else to concentrate on e.g. the work itself. This will help distract you from confidence issues and help prevent [over-analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis).
- '[Choking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(sports)#How_to_prevent_choking)' in sports is a related phenomenon. Here's some useful tips from that field:

> - Stay present - think about what needs to happen at that very moment. Not about what has happened or what might happen.
> - Control breathing and energy - provides a sense of control. Slowing down breathing and reducing muscle tension will allow the athlete to regain control of performance.
> - Let go of negative thoughts - move on without reacting to the negative thoughts.

- If the problem is severe and you can't control it by yourself, consider seeking out a course of [cognitive behavioural therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy) with a focus on [social anxiety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_anxiety). This should help you put into practice some techniques for dealing with social anxiety in a work context.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: That is indeed extremely useful! I have no idea where I can take such course. And my economical situation is about to get really awful. So, I really can't spend any money on that. (Fear not, I won't be fired!) If I were an athlete, I would be choking all the time. And those techniques seem a good idea to implement. And yes, I *may* suffer from social anxiety (I don't have medical evidence of such). But I really like the way you answered the (silly) question and compiled all the content in the comments here. I think I can't thank you enough.

Comment: No problem at all Ismael, if it's helped then I'm glad. And it's not a silly question at all! It's a very common problem. Personally I find I tend to hold onto the scenery (lectern etc) when giving presentations to groups of people - holding a pen as per Vietnhi Phuvan's advice below helps me with that.

Comment: I only gave a presentation once. And it went smoothly. The clients were important, but my boss was there. I was shaking! But it all went well. I think that having a pen would work for me too. I usually focus too much on how I look like and my phisical presentation. And sometimes the content (a.k.a. what I say to the client) has really poor quality.

Comment: If you're getting this with random people who only come into the office to ask directions then it sounds like it could be a mild case of social anxiety disorder - [check the symptoms](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/social-anxiety/Documents/signs%20and%20symptoms%20table%20v%204%20NHS%20choice.pdf). [Self-help therapies](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/stress-anxiety-depression/pages/self-help-therapies.aspx) are available, e.g. [this course here is recommended by the NHS and is pretty cheap](http://www.overcoming.co.uk/product/?pid=5195). If you have health insurance or you're in a country...

Comment: ... with universal healthcare then this is something that you could reasonably go and visit your doctor about - social anxiety disorder is a recognised condition, so you might not have the pay for the CBT yourself. If it's severe then SSRIs (medication) might be helpful. You might want to drop in on a [forum which specialises in SA](http://www.social-anxiety.org.uk/) and talk it over with them.

Comment: Those links are really useful. But sadly, I live in Portugal and those don't 'really' apply here. In fact, I have no idea what NHS and CBT are. But I might try to check a doctor for this. But I don't know where and how. But there must be something on Google.

Comment: NHS = National Health Service = Serviço Nacional de Saúde, CBT = Cognitive Behavioural Therapy. Your family doctor is probably a good place to start.

Comment: This got a bit awkward........... Lets just say that I, effectively, can say that I have no family. Therefore, I have no family doctor.

Comment: Sorry, I mean your regular doctor. Your [general practitioner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_practitioner). [These guys](http://www.apmgf.pt/), I think. [Medicina Geral e Familiar](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medicina_geral_e_familiar) - [Atenção primária à saúde](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aten%C3%A7%C3%A3o_prim%C3%A1ria_%C3%A0_sa%C3%BAde).

Comment: I dont have a 'general practitioner'. In fact, I don't see a doctor since I was 18! (except a while ago, when I had to make some exams.) But I will read the information there (later, not now) and I will act accordingly. I just hope I don't have to take any medicine. But thank you a lot for those links. Lets pray that the moderators see their high informational importance and don't delete them.

Comment: Ah. Then register with a doctor first, then go and see them. :)

Comment: I'm the most illiterate person when it comes to this kind of thing. I really know nothing. I had no one to tell me what to do, so, I'm always lost. But I will study and try to register for a doctor and see what else I can do. Thank you so much for your huge help!

Comment: Toastmasters, you probably have a local toastmasters club.  Very good at helping you build your public speaking skills.  https://www.toastmasters.org/

Comment: @DaveKaye That is an interesting idea. I spent only 2-3 minutes looking at it. But I will take a more serious look later on.

Comment: You have to be careful with "props" like pens or notebooks because you can start fiddling with them. That is, clicking a retractable pen multiple times, or tapping the pen on the notebook or a table. One that gets me during computer demonstrations is when the presenter jiggles the mouse.

Comment: Hello AE and Ismael, before cleaning up the comments, I want to give you a chance to summarize any valuable information from the comments in this answer as an [edit] to the post.  This helps others with similar problem find answers they seek, since only the content of the post itself is searchable.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

It generally depends, part of social interaction is building a **rapport** which means you're somewhat in-sync with them. Copying their actions is a great way to do this (e.g. sipping a drink when they do), so copying how they have their hands is a good way of doing this.

If I'm stood up I would generally have my hands to the side of me (which I don't always feel comfortable with) or clasped in-front of me like this picture

[image]

This looks fairly natural, and because you're stood up doesn't feel like you're placing barriers + being introverted to the client. You're also less likely to move your hands drawing attention to them so will probably feel a bit less self-conscious. I would be less inclined to do this if I were sat down.

Comment: Won't that look a bit pretencious? Btw, the example image you picked is portraiting Penn&Teller. Just to add to your answer. I will try that one, and I will update with the results.

Comment: You may think Penn and Teller can act pretentious, but their pose here is not. It is a normal pose in such a situation.

Comment: Looks a little studied to me, unless you're [defending a free kick](http://www.seriousgoalkeeping.net/Tactics/FreeKicks/images/Blackburn_Rovers_Defending_Free_Kick.png), but whatever comes naturally...

Comment: @Brandin I don't think they are pretentious. But the pose might not be the best one. I will try it anyway.

Comment: For those who can't get the reference: @AE is talking about football (soccer for habitants in the U.S.A), where people form a bareer and they place the hands like that to protect their.... jewels... so the ball doesn't hurt them.

Comment: @AE, no doubt it looks studied, Penn & Teller make their living with their hands, nothing about their posing, especially their hands, is incidental.

Comment: I really disagree with this answer. Holding your hands in front of your crotch looks strange -- it's what people do when they're uncomfortable in front of a crowd and don't know what to do with their hands.

Professional photographers (the ones that know what they're doing) make a big point of telling people to put their hands at their sides, or in their pockets, anything to look relaxed without putting hands in front of the crotch.

Comment: In toastmasters we call that pose "the fig leaf", and it's a big no-no. Better to be expressive with your hands.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n I think that's the point I'd the question. The individual is self conscious and doesn't have the confidence to use their hands in expression

Answer (score 3):

It's a cultural issue. Mediterranean peoples like to use their hands as a conversation enhancer. Using your hands when talking is a lot less common in the US. I personally like people who get passionate enough about a subject to start using their hands. The only caveat about using your hands in a conversation is that you should allow some extra physical space between you and your conversation partner. Keep in mind that some people do feel physically threatened when you start using your hands. In the US, I'd say keep your hands use to a minimum but don't leave them stiffly hanging by your sides either.

I'd say, talk to the client, get the client interested. If you are totally focused on communicating with the client and doing a thorough job of telling the client what the firm can do for them, the last and least thing you'll worry about is what your hands are doing and what to do about your hands.

Comment: I agree with your point of view, but it is actually extremely weird to have the hands in my pockets, while explaining to a client what we can do.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Absolutely not your hands in your pockets! Hold a prop like a pen - you may use the pen anyway to write something down, or an ipod or your business cards. If you are at an Expo, put some swag or business cards in your hand to give away to visitors to your booth.

Comment: I think that it would look stupid to hold a pen when talking with a client that only wants to know where is the store xyz. (It happens a lot.) But I will also try that. No doubt in there!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel If you are in a group social, you might consider keeping your hands empty but available so that you can shake anyone's hand at any time.

Comment: But a social group is different. In my opinion. But Yes, that is indeed a good point. Sometimes I just fiddle with my hands. Like touching all the fingers in my thumb, one at a time. It helps, but the hands are still hanging and it looks weird. But I will try new stuff.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I have a sweet tooth, so I've decided that holding a piece of Jolly Rancher hard candy works best for me - My pockets are, of course, filled with candy :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Meaning that I like candy, and if I had to put something in my hand to keep it busy, it might as well be candy :)

Comment: But I can't get any more fat. But it is a good idea to keep in mind.

Comment: Don't be holding an ipod. What kind of nonsense is that

Comment: @zfrisch OK, I get that you don't use an ipod to manage your contact info.

Comment: @zfrisch The iPod touch was really close-looking to the iPhone3. You can have your contact info there, just as you would in a cellphone. So, I see nothing wrong in having an iPod on your hands.

Comment: haha oh I see. I've only ever had an Ipod for music. I would never use it to store contact information, but admittedly I've had the same one for about 10 years, so to each their own.

Comment: Holding your smartphone isn't a bad idea though, if we're talking 'comfort objects'. :)

Comment: To add on this, politicians all around the world have known and abuse hand signals to make their point "stronger" and to go through their audience. Consider reading some articles on politicians and hand signals they use and for what purpose.